# print only lines that starts with digit from specific column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file which has second column as hostname of all hosts in my network:

```
Host example.com (x.x.x.x) is up (0.0041s latency).
```

And so on, but many lines doesn't start with hostname in second column it starts with IP of hostname like:

```
Host a.b.c.d is up (0.022s latency).
```

So how would I get all the lines that starts with IP in second column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$2~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/' file
```

This checks the second field `$2` against the regular expression. `[0-9]` matches a digit, `+` matches 1 or more digits, and `\.` matches a single dot.

Comment: Excellent work with nice explanation. Thank you so much.